# how much time does a particle take to complete an arc of a circle with a given velocity under gravitational force of Earth?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How much time would a particle take to travel to a height of $5R/3$ from lowest point along an arc, if given velocity $v$ at the lowest point? (circle is in vertical plane)

Comment: What's the effect of gravity on this? do we ignore gravity, or is gravity always there downwards?

Comment: Also, where do you get the centripetal force to maintain circular motion from?

Comment: Gravity is always downwards. Suppose an ant moving on tyre of a bicycle. Velocity of ant is v at lowest point and tyre is at rest. This way question can be visualised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no friction, conservation of energy means that
$$E=\frac12mV^2+mgh=\frac12mR^2\dot\theta^2-mgR\cos\theta=\frac12mv^2-mgR$$
Where $m$ is the particle's mass, $g$ is the acceleration of gravity, $\theta$ is the angle along the arc from the lowest point, $R$ is the arc's radius $V=R\dot\theta$ is the particle's current speed, and $v$ is its initial speed.
Then
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\dot\theta=\sqrt{\frac{v^2}{R^2}-\frac{2g}R(1-\cos\theta)}=\frac vR\sqrt{1-\frac{4gR}{v^2}\sin^2\frac{\theta}2}$$
Then if we let $\phi=\frac{\theta}2$ we have
$$\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4gR}{v^2}\sin^2\phi}}=\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\phi}}=\frac{v}{2R}dt$$
Where $k=\sqrt{\frac{4gR}{v^2}}$. When we are at $h+R=\frac{5R}3$ above the lowest point, $\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac23\right)$, so $\phi=\frac12\cos^{-1}\frac23=\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac56}$
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\frac12\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac23\right)}\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\phi}}&=\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac56}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-k^2x^2}}\\
&=F\left(\sqrt{\frac56},k\right)=\frac v{2R}\int_0^Tdt=\frac v{2R}T\end{align}$$
Where $F(x,k)$ is the [incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1180573453) and $T$ is how long it takes.

**EDIT**: Per @low iq's comment, the angle has been fixed. Also there is the problem that $1<k<\sqrt{\frac65}$ is possible, but elliptic integrals are only tabulated for $0<k<1$. In that case the substitution $y=kx$ seems in order, so
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac56}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-k^2x^2}}&=\frac1k\int_0^{k\sqrt{\frac56}}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-\frac1{k^2}y^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}}\\
&=\frac1kF\left(k\sqrt{\frac56},\frac1k\right)=\frac v{2R}T\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks. This helps a lot. I was stuck with this problem for a week.

Comment: I think it should be cosine inverse -2/3.

Comment: Yep. You're right. Fixed. Also there was a bit of a problem if $1<k<\sqrt{\frac65}$ which I addressed. The high-$k$ issue is common for a pendulum that doesn't have sufficient energy to get to the top of the circle.

Comment: What modifications are needed if surface has coefficient of friction u

Comment: The problem gets a lot messier. The radial force is $$ma_r=m\ddot r-mr\dot\theta^2=-mR\dot\theta^2=-N+mg\cos\theta$$ and the tangential force is $$ma_{\theta}=mr\ddot\theta+2m\dot r\dot\theta=mR\ddot\theta=-\mu N-mg\sin\theta$$ so then you would have to eliminate the normal force $N$ between the equations, then make the substitution $\omega=\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ and that gives you a first order linear differential equation for $\omega^2$ so you could maybe integrate that and hopefully solve the result for $\omega$ and try to integrate again to find $\theta$.

Comment: can we add work done by friction in equation of conservation of energy and find time required?

Comment: by going the way you explained, I got ode like dw/dt+w^2=expression involving theta.

Comment: I don't think I can find time by solving differential equation for theta in case of presence of friction.